# Detox tests hang with pending items on dispatch queue

Tags: ios, react-native, detox

I am writing e2e tests on Detox to test a Firebase app in React Native. It looks like the call to `firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(number)` dispatches some items on the dispatch queue but these items don't ever seem to be dequeued and therefore the tests cannot proceed. My hunch is that there is a network request being made by the sign in call that never resolves.
Here is the log:

```
detox[41991] INFO:  [APP_STATUS] The app is busy with the following tasks:
• There are 2 work items pending on the dispatch queue: "Main Queue (<OS_dispatch_queue_main: com.apple.main-thread>)".
• Run loop "Main Run Loop" is awake.
```

I have read through [this](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Troubleshooting.Synchronization.md) troubleshooting guide and it looks like the operation is on the **Main thread (native)** and the issue is a **waiting too much** issue.

Is there a way to inspect the items on the dispatch queue to further understand what they are? I have tried running the `/usr/bin/xcrun simctl spawn <device> log stream --level debug --style compact --predicate 'process == "myapp"'` but I don't understand the output. If it is useful I can upload the logs.

I'm hoping I can post some logs of some sort and someone can help me to find the reason for the items on the dispatch queue or point me in the right direction.
I have no experience with native development so device system logs and Objective C/Swift code mean nothing to me.
Thanks

- Detox version: `19.4.2`
- React Native version: `0.67.4`
- Node version:    `v12.22.6`
- Device model: `iPhone 11 Simulator`
- OS: `iOS`
- Test-runner    (select one): `jest-circus`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question: No,there is no easy way to inspect the dispatch queue. You must go through the internals of the app, add logging, and comment-out portions of the code until you figure out what is causing the issue.

---

**EDIT: As of 2022-08-07, updating your** `@react-native-firebase/*` **packages to** `>=v15.3.0` **should fix the issue.**

---

About your specific synchronization problem...

This problem is caused by a bug in the `@react-native-firebase/messaging` implementation of `application: didReceiveRemoteNotification: fetchCompletionHandler:`[!].

Their implementation gets into a race with `FIRAuth/didReceiveRemoteNotification` which causes react-native-firebase/messaging to not callback the completion handler if FIRAuth's function ran first.

A [PR is in progress](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/pull/6392) for this to be fixed upstream, but in the meantime you can use the following patch if you have set-up [patch-package](https://github.com/ds300/patch-package):

```
diff --git a/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/messaging/ios/RNFBMessaging/RNFBMessaging+AppDelegate.m b/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/messaging/ios/RNFBMessaging/RNFBMessaging+AppDelegate.m
index ec26b70..743fe41 100644
--- a/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/messaging/ios/RNFBMessaging/RNFBMessaging+AppDelegate.m
+++ b/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/messaging/ios/RNFBMessaging/RNFBMessaging+AppDelegate.m
@@ -123,6 +123,18 @@ - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
     completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
     return;
   }
+
+  // If the notification is a probe notification, always call the completion 
+  // handler with UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData.
+  //
+  // This fixes a race condition between `FIRAuth/didReceiveRemoteNotification` and this
+  // module causing detox to hang when `FIRAuth/didReceiveRemoteNotification` is called first.
+  // see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72044950/detox-tests-hang-with-pending-items-on-dispatch-queue/72989494
+  NSDictionary *data = userInfo[@"com.google.firebase.auth"];
+  if (data && data[@"warning"]) {
+      completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
+      return;
+  }
 #endif
 
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
```

[!]in *@react-native-firebase/messaging/ios/RNFBMessaging/RNFBMessaging+AppDelegate.m*